# Why Smooch not receiving Images from admin?

Tags: smooch

I implemented Smooch in my project and configured it to receive emails when my users message me. When a user sends an image from our app our admins receive them but if the admin tries to reply with an image it doesn't, the admin can only respond with text.

How can I send image replies to my users over email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Smooch doesn't support responding to users with image attachments via email. The best workaround that exists now is to post your image somewhere internet visible and send the user a link.

Note that other Smooch business app integrations do support sending images to users using a special syntax that looks like this: `![](image_url_here)`, however this syntax is not currently supported by the business-facing email channel. You can find more info about these special syntaxes [here](http://blog.smooch.io/how-to-make-buttons-images-payments-with-smooch-a-syntax-cheatsheet/).